# Where in the file system are applications installed?

Tags: applications, files, shell, adb

I have installed a few Android applications both with the `adb install MyApplication.apk` command and via a webserver (like an alternative to Android Market).

But where in the Android file system on my phone is the `MyApplication.apk` file placed? Are applications installed with `adb install` not placed in the same directory as applications downloaded from the Market?

I found some applications on `/system/app` but I can't recognize them as some downloaded from Android Market or the one I have installed with `adb install`.

Where on the system is applications that I have installed located?

My phone is not rooted, and I am running Nexus One with Android 2.2.1.

Comment: Related: [Where Android apps store data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218507/218526)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Where an app is stored very much depends on several criteria:

- System apps / pre-installed-bloatware-apps are stored in `/system/app` with privileged apps in `/system/priv-app`
  (which are mounted read-only to prevent any changes). You may also find system apps in `/custpack/app`'s subdirectories.
- normal apps in internal memory go to `/data/app`
- some apps (encrypted on internal storage?) go to `/data/app-private`
- Apps stored on external memory go to an encrypted container in `/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure`. As at runtime Android needs them to be decrypted, it will decrypt them and store a decrypted copy on `tmpfs` (so it's gone on a reboot) in `/mnt/asec`
  (you cannot simply look into `/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure` directly from the device; but if you use a card reader and attach the card to your PC, you will see the files there have the extension `.asec` instead of `.apk` -- from which you will get the connection to the name `/mnt/asec`).
- the apps data are stored below `/data/data/<package_name>` (internal storage) or on external storage, if the developer sticks to [the rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), below `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<package_name>`.

Comment: Is this answer equally valid for KitKat, Lollipop, and Marshmallow?

Comment: @jdmc I cannot tell for Nougat yet, and have no Marshmallows to check – but to my knowledge, yes.

Comment: @Izzy gotta wonder what early-web archaeologists will think about that comment in 100 years time..

Comment: @geotheory they might think we get paid in sweets :)

Comment: Yup, this seems to remain valid on Marshmallow.

Comment: Android older than K (exclusive) does not have `/system/priv-app`. Instead everything goes to `/system/app`.

Comment: @Izzy Thansk a lot for this precise info. can I kindly ask you to provide link to sources / references you used? I'd like to check if all this still applies to latest version of Android, especially 10+.

Comment: After 9 years anyone is unlikely to remember the precise sources used for an answer, @Pascal – so I'm afraid you'll have to do with the source mentioned in my answer. It still holds true, roughly (not sure if `/custpack/` is still used), though a few "levels" have been added. Most things you can compare on-device even without root.

Answer (score 34):

They are stored in `/data/app/` but unless your phone is rooted all you will see is an empty folder.

Comment: My Droid Bionic is rooted, but the data folder is still displaying empty in DDMS!

Comment: @IgorG. I've never used DDMS and I have barely any experience with eclipse so I don't think I can help.  I'd ask this as a new question.

Comment: If you're using DDMS, it is not querying the device as a 'root' user would so the /data folder is empty.  You can either use `adb shell` and then `su` to root, or `chmod 777 /data` and `chmod 777 /data/app` to allow DDMS to list the contents.  Just make sure you set the permissions of these folders back to 771 when you're done.

Answer (score 6):

On my Android 4.0.4 (ICS) Xperia ray, they are stored in `/mnt/asec/XXX-1/pkg.apk`.
`XXX` is the Google Play ID of the application.
For example, Firefox is found at `/mnt/asec/org.mozilla.firefox-1/pkg.apk` and Skype is found at `/mnt/asec/com.skype.raider-1/pkg.apk`.

Following [zuul's comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002#comment35152_28155) I took these screenshots from my phone to confirm my answer.

### [**Firefox**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox)

[image: Firefox]

### [**Stopwatch & Countdown Timer**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.be.android.stopwatch)

[image: Stopwatch]

And these are my phone's details:

[image: My Xperia Ray details]

Comment: Do you have any official link to substantiate this, as to provide more information about this change?

Comment: no, I don't have any link and I cannot take screenshots on my unrooted Xperia Ray. If you're using an app like X-plore or Solid Explorer, you can navigate to that directory to verify it.

Comment: @Zuul: I still haven't got any link but I've managed to take screenshots from my phone to ***substantiate*** the claim. And... if you've got any link to prove otherwise, post it here so I also get informed.

Comment: No links mentioning otherwise, I asked if you had any link for me to read about the "why" that lead to their decision on changing the directory structure. Later on, I'll look into Google's Documentation and get back to you with the link for you to place on your answer. Thank you for the trouble with the screenshots, +1 from me.

Comment: Though it just applies to the de-crypted copy of apps installed on external storage (check with the `mount` command and wonder: `/mnt/asec` uses `tmpfs`, a temporary filesystem created in RAM -- and thus gone on reboot, together with all the apps =:-0)

Comment: Nexus one has the same directory ( Android 2.3.6 ), but only for some apps, some aren't there

Answer (score 2):

On my Kindle Fire many of the apks I haven't installed from my app store (apks from outside sources, e.g.:Aptoide,etc.) are in my downloads folder. The others I find in my /system/app folder.