# Where are the .apk files of currently installed apps stored on my Android device?

Tags: applications, files, storage, apk, file-system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where in the file system are applications installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed)

How can I view the .apk files of currenly installed apps on my android phone?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use a file manager to look in the following locations:

1. `/data/app`
2. `/data/app-private`
3. `/system/app/`
4. `/sdcard/.android_secure` (shows .asec files, not .apks)
   On Samsung phones: `/sdcard/external_sd/.android_secure`

You need to be rooted to view the first three.

Use command `pm list package -f` (via `adb shell` if you want to use ADB) to list packages with their respective locations. You can then read the files. This can be done without superuser permissions.

Comment: Matthew, you can consider an update to the answer. Android need not  be  rooted to access `/system/app/` now.

Answer (score 0):

System apps are found in `/system/app/`.

The other apps you've installed are found in the `/mnt/asec/` directory. See [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28155/18442) to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002) for details.