# Where is a downloaded .apk placed in Android phones?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where in the file system are applications installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed)

Where is a downloaded .apk placed in Android phones? I want to backup the .apk files to my PC so that if something happens I will just restore the applications instead of re-downloading them from market.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S II.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't have root access, it doesn't matter because you won't be able to back them up.

If you do have root access, use an app like [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to back up the apks.

**Note:**

This doesn't really answer the question of where to find the downloaded APKs, but it does address the need of the OP.

Comment: While a very good answer to the asker's situation, it would be nice if it *also* actually answered the question listed as the title, or at least noted that it doesn't answer it for a purpose.

Comment: @IlariKajaste: good point. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

They're ([mainly](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/view-apk-files)) in `/data/app`.  If you're rooted, you can also back them up to your computer via [ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html):

```
adb pull /data/app/ C:\backup\
```

(Or similar command).  To restore the easiest might be to copy them to your SD card, then go through them on your phone and install one by one.

Titanium is much better though, so listen to Nathan.