# How to pull the apks from my android phone

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, adb, apk

I have a rooted android phone. I am trying to pull the applications from /system/app/. However this simply does not copy the apk. What I have tried.

```
    adb shell
    su
    cd data
    cd app
    ls
```

A lot of applications are shown. However when I try to pull it it says

```
adb pull /data/app test

pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
```

When I try to pull it from the system/app it pulls it but no file is created on my computer. I have specified the file name, tried with it and without it. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have also tried it individually with specific apks. But that doesnt work either.

Comment: Releated http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/where-is-a-downloaded-apk-placed-in-android-phones and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/where-are-the-apk-files-stored-on-my-android-device

Comment: I have gone through them. My issue is that I cant use adb pull to copy the apk onto my pc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `su` to get root privileges when you shell in (which you've indicated you are) then that means you're not root on the shell by default. `adb pull` fails with that error message because it doesn't have permission to index the directory and pull the contents.

You should be able to restart `adb` on your device with `adb root` first:

```
adb root
adb pull /data/app/
```

And a fully illustrative example to show that this is the likely issue (I used `/data/misc` just because it's smaller):

```
[09:27:23] ~/adb-test $ adb pull /data/misc/
pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped.  <-------------- Same issue because we're not root yet!
[09:27:49] ~/adb-test $ adb root
[09:27:56] ~/adb-test $ adb pull /data/misc/
pull: building file list...
... Snip all of the individual files here ...
24 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
65 KB/s (7732 bytes in 0.115s)
[09:27:59] ~/adb-test $
```

---

Another option for restarting `adb` as root is [Chainfire's adbd insecure app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590). Some ROMs will not support the `adb root` command, though, as they were not built to allow it. This will be true if you root a stock ROM without installing a custom one, for example.

Comment: It says adbd cannot run as root in production builds

Comment: Sounds like something is not right with root.  Which device is this, and how was it rooted?

Comment: Also, some hits on Google search for this error seem to indicate that this could also be fixed with different USB drivers.

Comment: @Sab: You can try the [adbd insecure app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590) instead, although it costs a nominal fee. Your ROM may not support the `adb root` command, unfortunately. Another option would be to try to find either a boot image that supported unsecure `adbd` startup or a different ROM entirely.

Comment: @Chahk- The phone is rooted properly as far as i know and i have checked it using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en.

Comment: @eldarerathis So i just install the apk into the phone and run it and it should work? Or is it a better option to just use a custom rom

Comment: @Sab: In theory yes, you just install the app and run it to restart `adbd` as root (you get a 15 minute refund window if you want to test it). A custom ROM would be free and you wouldn't have to worry about using the app, but a bit more involved to install. You could probably go either way, but I think those might be the only real options to get `adb pull` working on restricted directories, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sab: Also, now that I look at the XDA thread again, Chainfire has provided a download to the app for free on the forums (bottom of the first post), so you can try it without worry.

Comment: Yep. I realized that now.But for expirience sake I guess i will install a custom ROm. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You do not need adb to run as root to pull the actual files, but you do need it to run as root to list the directory in which they are located (which would be an implicit requirement to pulling the whole directory).

If you want to do it without root, pull /data/system/packages.xml and extract the code paths of the applications from there, then adb pull them individually by their full path names.  That could be a great opportunity to learn about grep and xargs - or use your favorite host-side scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the latest version of ADB utility by downloading the newest Android SDK version from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

The syntax is `adb pull <path to apk> <path on PC>`.  For "path on PC" portion try specifying the full path, with drive letter like so:

`adb pull /data/app/myapp.apk c:\test`

To pull **all** of the apps from /data/app directory try this:

`adb pull /data/app/ c:\test`

Comment: Let me update the adb and try. Syntax wise I dont think I am making any error.

Comment: You were missing the "`/`" after the source path if you were trying to pull the entire directory.

Comment: I guess that was a typo besides it doesnt work with individual apks either. My system/app shows that these many bytes have been transferred but I dont see anything in the directory where I run adb pull or anywhere else.

Comment: Actually no, the closing `/` isn't necessary after all.