# Suspicious Permissions And A Safe Repository?

Tags: applications, security, apk, permissions

I have found **[older version of Facebook For Android app here](http://fullapk.net/108/facebook-apk-for-android/)** which was hosted on geekfiles.in

When i wanted to install 1.8.1 and checked permissions, the following arose my suspicions:

**Services that cost you money:**
*Send SMS messages*

**Your messages:**
*edit SMS or MMS, read SMS or MMS, receive SMS*

**Your accounts:**
*act as an account authenticator, manage the accounts list*

**Phone calls:**
*read phone state and identity*

**Your accounts:**
*discover known accounts*

**Storage:**
*modify/delete SD card contents*

Can unscrupulous people inject malware into APKs? If yes, what are trusted repositories for downgrading apps to older versions?

Is **[this repository](http://www.freewarelovers.com/android/app/facebook-for-android)** trusted source?

Comment: For future reference, you can use something like Titanium Backup to make backups of previous app versions and revert to them if something goes wrong (This saved my bacon when I almost got locked out of my Google account due to a botched Authenticator update).

Comment: I am UNrooted as long as i have actual warranty, so cannot use Titanium Backup yet. I used MyBackup full version but could not find Facebook For Android .APK file and all that i have found was Facebook Messenger.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, I don't trust any "freeware" or "shareware" site that has not specifically been recommended to me by someone I know and trust, and because these sites aren't my thing I can't either recommend or condemn this specific example. I can answer part of your question, though, and say an emphatic **yes, unscrupulous people can inject malware into APKs.** Installing an APK from an unknown source is generally a very bad idea.

The permissions you mention, though, are actually the same that the [legit Facebook for Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) asks over in the Play store (see the "Permissions" tab). Permissions alone are a bad judge of an APK's potential for harm. In this case, personally, I would say the risk of an unknown source far outweighs the app's permission requests.

Comment: I wouldn't install an APK from a non-trusted source either.

Comment: @Mr. Buster Not the same actually. I don't see legit Facebook for Android app asking permission to send/receive SMS messages.

Comment: @Boris_yo - the SMS/MMS permissions I see are Send, Edit, Receive, and Read per the Play Market.

Comment: @Mr.Buster I see now that since version 1.8 send/receive SMS messages permissions were removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to downgrade an APK, the best way is to get it from another device that you trust using one of the methods in  [Where are the .apk files of currently installed apps stored on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/where-are-the-apk-files-stored-on-my-android-device)  Then you can put that APK on your device.

Comment: After using MyBackup full version, i can only find Facebook Messenger .APK file but no Facebook For Android.