# Where is the apk file stored in android phones?

Tags: apk

Where is the apk file stored when it is downloaded from 9apps? I can't find it.

Comment: See: [Where in the file system are applications installed?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3002/16575) / [Where are the .apk files of currently installed apps stored on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4510/16575) when talking about *installed* apps.

Comment: apks are stored in /data/apps/ when its installed in your system.

Comment: @ShihabSoft : But the question is about where it is downloaded not Installed? Unless the location is same for 9Apps. But that's good you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded the apk from the internet like it sounds it would most likely be stored in your download folder.