# Find the file referred to by a home screen icon

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, malware, antivirus

I have an icon in my home screen that I haven't installed and looks like malware (Logo of O2, which is not my network, with the name "Priority". I opened it once and it showed commercials).

Last week there was another strange app installed too which I just removed from the home screen. However, I would like to know what is the file behind this "O2 Priority" icon that appeared in my home screen so I can delete it. Is there any way to do that? Any help appreciated.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S6
Android: 5.1.1

Comment: [O2 priority](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goldengekko.o2pm) is an legitimate app. It might be a way of advertising to make you install the app. There can be various reasons for this to occur in your homescreen - some other adware app, visiting a website can cause this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are the .apk files of currently installed apps stored on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/where-are-the-apk-files-of-currently-installed-apps-stored-on-my-android-device)