# Android encryption and Native Library Storage Locations

Tags: encryption, native-library

I have written an app that uses a native shared library via the Android NDK. I am particularly interested to know whether the .so file is stored in a location that would be encrypted if I were to enable encryption on the phone.

When that app is installed on the phone, where does the .so file get stored Also, is there only one or multiple copies of that .so file on the phone?

Comment: Is the device rooted? It would be fairly easy for you to answer your own question if the device is rooted? Watch the `/data` and notice changes during the app installation. Then filter the changes to find the thing you want.

Comment: no the device is a non rooted samsung S3, I think its running 4.2 or thereabouts

Comment: am i right in thinking that apps store there .apk file in the /data dir? the .so file must exist within the .apk - is it copied elsewhere also? i.e. is there an android equivalent of /usr/local/lib? would the /data dir be encrypted?

Comment: Izzy has the things covered. See : [Where Android apps store data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/47951) / [Android Folder Hierarchy](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46934) / [Where in the file system are applications installed?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28231)

Comment: yes - need to read and understand that, maybe I could run a find type command over adb as well to locate all instances of the .so on the phone?

Comment: If the device is not rooted, `find` wouldn't be able to give you what you want.

Comment: also need to find a doc on what storage locations are encrypted when you do the standard android encrypt phone procedure. I'm assuming its not the whole file system, maybe just the android equivalent of the /home dir, though that assumption could well be wrong

Comment: I'm not certain but `/data` seems to be the only thing encrypted as per this link: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/encryption/

Comment: quite a technical article, but suggests that /data *is* encrypted with fill disk encryption. question remains how to be sure that the .so file has not proliferated to any other file locations - hopefully not..

Comment: @Firelord if you want to concatenate any/all of your comments into an answer I am happy to accept that - they have solved my problem..

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not confident that I've solved your problem. Perhaps, somebody with better expertise can provide a high-quality answer to your question.