# Remove Google App from non-rooted phone

Tags: uninstallation, default-applications

[image: Google App]

Is it possible to Uninstall [Google App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) without root permissions ?

It consumes more internal memory and drains battery.

I already gone through a thread to **disable it** but uninstalling may free-up some space and saves battery.

Comment: AFAIK, no. It's considered as a system app and thus, impossible to remove (though I'm curious how you disabled it without root)

Comment: Its my primary phone that's why I'm worried off. rooting makes phone bit unstable and shows annoying popups asking root permissions every time.

Comment: I would just disable it just as you would do to any bloatware, but besides removing updates it is impossible to completely remove the app.

Comment: It's not rooting which causes those (annoying) popups. It's a superuser app which shows them whenever an app demands root access, and you would see them if only you've not set a custom default policy. // I'm curious how exactly did you conclude that rooting decreases any amount of stability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just about Google apps. You can't remove any system app without root privileges. The reason is very simple. You need higher privileges (system; root) to write the `system` partition which contains those system apps and you don't have it. `system` partition is mounted in read-only mode by-default.

Unless that partition is already mounted in read-write mode, a system app uninstaller would first have to remount the partition in read-write mode and then would begin the procedure of removing the app. To remount, they require root permissions while you're asking something impossible here.

Thinking about [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) wouldn't help here because it doesn't have the privilege to remount that partition too.

As for freeing some disk space, know that disabling those Google apps and clearing their data from **Settings → Apps → All apps** should be enough because even if you somehow end up achieving the impossible, you won't be able to see any difference since the [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) issue is associated with `data` partition, not with `system`. 
See [Where in the file system are applications installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3002/96277)

As for any concern about the battery, you may be able to save some juice using [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify).