# Why do the *.asec files dissapear from /sdcard/.android_secure when phone boots?

Tags: sd-card, app2sd

I have been puzzled by this for sometime, I have found out that these *.asec files migrate to /mnt/secure/asec on my phone after it boots but it still seems they occupy space within the sdcard and if you delete any of the .asec files in /mnt/secure/asec a corresponding space is also released in the sdcard though they are nowhere to be found within the sdcard.

After switching off the phone everything goes back to its place and the files are visible in the .android_secure folder or when sdcard is removed, I would really like to understand this behaviour, what happens in phone to cause this??

Comment: See the fourth bullet point of the answer [Where in the file system are applications installed?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/28231). For queries, ping the poster there. :)

Comment: [Why root cannot access “.android_secure” directory on external SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221485/218526)