# Where is data/data?

Tags: applications, internal-storage

I play Minecraft but I don't​ know where are my files saved  (I opt "Application" as my storage). Many people say it's on `data/data` but when I go to root/data, it doesn't have any folder including root/data/data. My phone has only one storage. No SD card.

How to find my app data?

Answer (score 3):

Application data is stored under `/data/data` , which cannot be seen by user unless your​ device is rooted and the file explorer you use has root privileges enabled

Related [Where in the file system are applications installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3002/131553)