# App Data Not Restored After Copy From Nearby Device

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 7.0-nougat, data-transfer, device-migration

When installing a new Android 7.0 phone I chose the option to *Copy From Nearby Device*. All the apps on the older Android 4.4 device were copied and seem to be working but only 4 actually have any data in them: Gmail, Calendar, Hangouts (but not Hangouts Dialer) and Contacts. Every other app is an a cleanly freshly installed state: No accounts, no data, no saved games, etc.

**What happened and how can I correct this?** The older device is not rooted and neither is the new one yet (but I intend to do so once I figure out why).

Comment: It won't copy data for specific apps, it will install the apps, so you have to login/setup those individual apps.  That is working how it is intended to.

Comment: @RMarkwald - Really? That make's pretty useless. One can easily get the list of previously installed app from Play Store, but the data is unreproducible and most valuable! I was sure that it worked between two other devices of the same Android version but I will try to double-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible reasons

- From [Nexus help](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6073630?hl=en)

> When you set up your phone, you can quickly import Google Accounts, **backed-up apps**, and data from your current Android device to your new Nexus phone by using Tap & Go.

(Emphasis Supplied)

Kit Kat didn't have the cloud backup, IIRC, so it can't be whereas whatever is backed up is Google account stuff

- Again from [Google help](https://support.google.com/nexus/forum/AAAANseOu18QvrdTL1NRq4/?hl=en), of you scroll down the long list of complaints, you will notice problems when both the devices were *not* of same version. This cannot be concluded as the main cause as it is not documented officially, but the first one is more likely IMO.

On a side note, transfer from Huawei device on KitKat to Lollipop worked but not KitKat to Marshmallow (personal experience), that's why I was sceptical about it in answering your [earlier question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179798/131553)

Comment: Would updating kitkat to lollipop improve the situation? It is something that at least my phone is offering.